# Should I edit an almost answer to my question to make it correct and then accept it?

Tags: discussion, edits, accepted-answer

I had a problem I couldn't resolve so I appeal to SO and got several answers, none of which worked. After a few more hours of playing around, I managed to get the solution one person proposed to work with a bit of extra tinkering. I edited his answer and then accepted it. Is that ok to do? I didn't want to answer it myself since he led me to the solution, and I didn't want to bug him to add in the edit bit I needed since I could easily do it.

This may be considered a dupe of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46840/accepting-almost-correct-answer-that-helped-analyze-the-problem), but my question really is asking if I can go ahead and add the extra component needed for the solution to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on how close the answer is to being right.

If it's 95% there then edit it making it clear which is your modification and accept it.

If it only pointed you in the right direction vote it up but add your own (possibly CW) answer with the solution.

However, that's just my opinion.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't realized 'til this answer that editing someone else's answer was possible.

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, rather than editing the answer or making a new one to show the corrected version, I'd update my question with the corrected code and acknowledge the fact that it was based on one of the answers and accept it.  It should be acknowledged in both the update and a comment on the answer along with the changes that are needed to work.  That way, it is clearer for other readers that while this answer almost completely answers the question, there are some changes needed to fit your situation and you're not putting words into the answerer's mouth.  Also the answerer will have the opportunity to update the answer himself.

Comment: I don't like this. The page is a lot more readable when the question just contains the question and the answer(s) contain, guess what, the answer. Your proposal creates a misleading page, where one could easily believe that the accepted answer contains all the interesting information and miss the details that are, surprisingly, in the question.

Answer (score 2):

What I used to do is to add a comment explaining why this answer is *almost* what I was looking for and then accept it anyway. If the answer needs some hard work to be acceptable to me, I upvote the answer and add my own answer as accepted.

I have never found a problem acting like this and the answerers seems to accept it kindly. Also, I have seen this kind of arrangement in a lot of questions of others and it was really clear and gentle to me as a reader.