# What is desired practice for deriving answers from comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, best-practices

If I ask a question on SO and someone comments on it, not solving the problem, but leading to my solution nonetheless, what is the best way to handle assigning the correct answer? I could just answer it myself with a full explaination, but at the same time, I wouldn't have solved the problem otherwise. What is the best way to handle credit in such a case?

Comment: Well, this is semi-dupe of two old discussions: [How to react when the right answer is given in the comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194969) and [Accepting “almost correct” answer that helped analyze the problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46840)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I like Robert's answer more than all those answers in the duplicated

Comment: @Braiam agreed, didn't expect official answer now when it was discussed years ago. Anyway closed the relevant one as duplicate of this one. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard actually, the most "official" response about the topic was Jeff in SF meta... which posted a comment, and was stolen to make an answers O_o [How to handle unanswered questions that have the answer in a comment or edited into the question?](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Just answer it**; there's no further ceremony or citation needed.

Answers posted in comments are a big problem because comments do not support features like proper voting and the wiki-style editing that allow us to edit and improve that content. They will probably be deleted anyway (or at least they should).

Yes, every once in awhile, a "half-answer comment" might spur a *real* answer to be posted, but the problem remains that that all those unfinished, unvetted *answers-in-a-comment* remain very conspicuously at the top of the thread where the **voting** is supposed to determine which answers rises to the top. Unfortunately, incoming users wont likely understand that nuance between a proper answer and one that is *"just a comment."*

Personally, I don't like an answer bulked up with a lot of needless backstory and commentary. Something that starts, *"according to this comment [link], so and so said… which got me thinking…"* just buries the *actual* answer under a lot of unnecessary verbosity. I would just answer the question with something awesome and don't worry about the comments from folks who didn't have the time nor the inclination to post a proper answer.

Comment: `Something that starts, "according to this comment [link], so and so said… which got me thinking…" just buries the actual answer under a lot of unnecessary verbosity.` **Solution:** Acknowledge the comment at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @dorukayhan In my opinion, that's just drawing *more* attention to an activity that **we are fundamentally trying to discourage.** Great answer here: **[How to handle questions that have the answer in a comment..."](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931/1581)**